# Nested square brackets in tensor indices

Tags: mathematical-physics, tensors, convention

I know that using square brackets on tensor indicies denote the anti-symmetric part

$$ T_{[ab]} = \frac{1}{2} \left( T_{ab} - T_{ba} \right)$$

I now have to prove that

$$ T_{a [[bc]d]} = T_{a [bcd]} $$

But I'm not sure what to do with the nested square brackets. Does this mean the following?

$$ T_{a [[bc]d]} = \frac{1}{2} \left( T_{a[bc]d} - T_{ad[bc]} \right)$$

Comment: Shouldn't it be $T_{a[[bc]d]}=T_{a[b[cd]]}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the expansion of last expression on the right does not have terms with $d$ in the third slot, whereas $T_{a[bcd]}$ does.

One doesn't see nested brackets in practice (exactly because of the identity you're proving), but I'd interpret them to mean that one skews first over $bc$, and then skews over $bcd$. In other words,
$$T_{a[[bc]d]} = \frac{1}{2}(T_{a[bcd]} - T_{a[cbd]}),$$
and at this stage the proof should be easy.

Comment: What does $[bcd]$ means?

Comment: It denotes that we're forming the total alternation of $T$ in those indices: $T_{a[bcd]} = \frac{1}{3!} \sum_{\sigma \in S_3} (\text{sgn }\sigma) T_{a\sigma(b)\sigma(c)\sigma(d)}$. NB that the first index just comes along for the ride. The factor of $\frac{1}{3!}$ is chosen so that if $T$ is already totally skew in $bcd$ then $T_{a[bcd]} = T_{abcd}$ (rather than some nonunit multiple thereof).

Comment: Is the second 1/2 in the original answer correct?

Comment: No, thanks for the catch, I've corrected it.